# Importing crude oil prices from WolframAlpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, databases

WolframAlpha has knowledge of crude oil prices, as a simple query will show. I am trying to obtain this data for use in Mathematica but I am not able to figure out the input.

If I try

```
FinancialData["SC.NYMEX"]
```

The result is that this is not a known entity. Do I need to find another source or is there a simple way to access historical prices for the past 10 years directly from the Wolfram database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the prices from the [Energy Information Administration](http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_fut_s1_d.htm).

```
RCLC1d = Import["http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist_xls/RCLC1d.xls"];
c1 = RCLC1d[[2, All, {1, 2}]];
c1prices = Cases[Drop[c1, 3], {_, _?NumberQ}];

DateListPlot[c1prices, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "WTI Oil Price since " <> 
   DateString[
    c1prices[[1, 1]], {"Day", " ", "MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}], 
 FrameLabel -> {None, Style["$", Large]}, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit, still the lazy way:

[image]

Go the lazy way and try the folling

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I have done that. But what I would like to do is to import this into mathematical  for further treatment. At the moment I don't know how to do it.